# Foliate with landscape number in portrait pages

Tags: numbering, page-numbering, rotating

I really don't know if this is possible but in LaTeX should be. I have a `.tex` document and what i what is to write the page number (with a format like 0001, 0002, 0003, ...) in the slightly top-right side with a 90 degree rotation.

Like the picture.

[image]

How can i achieve that?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[text={6in,8in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}


\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\setlength\doublerulesep{2.5em} 

\begin{document}

\begin{flushright}
{\Large \bf Some title}
\end{flushright}

\hrule

\begin{flushright}
    \begin{scriptsize}
    My name\\
    Location\\
    Number\\
    e-mail
    \end{scriptsize}
\end{flushright}

\vspace{3em}

\begin{multicols}{2}
    \lipsum[1-4]
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Please provide some code for a minimal document. This should include the class you are using and any packages or config you already have affecting the page layout, headers and footers.

Comment: @cfr Ready. My `.tex`  is long and mostly use the tabular enviroment but this code have the packages i'm using.

Comment: Off-topic: `\bf` is 20+ years obsolete for use in LaTeX and ought not be used. You could use `fancyhdr` or something like that for the header. Or there is the `background` package. `rotating` lets you rotate boxes. Ti*k*Z is an option, but would be overkill here. (Possibly a reason not to use `background`.) `everypage`, `eso-pic` ....

Answer (score 1):

A solution without changing `\thepage`, by using `\AtEverypageHook` and a `TikZ` overlay, padding the page number with `0` as desired, the format can be changed within the `\paddedpagenumber` macro.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{everypage}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage{blindtext}


\pagestyle{empty}% Remove all other heading etc. contents on the page, perhaps using fancyhdr is a better option here if content other than the page number should remain.

\newcommand{\paddedpagenumber}{%
  \ifnum10>\value{page}%
  000%
  \else
  \ifnum100>\value{page}%
  00%
  \else
  \ifnum1000>\value{page}%
  0%
  \fi
  \fi
  \fi
  \arabic{page}%
}

\newcommand{\rotatedpagenumber}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \node[rotate=-90,font={\large\bfseries}] (A) at ($(current page.north east) - (1.5cm,4cm)$) {\paddedpagenumber};% Change the spacing here at will. 
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\AddEverypageHook{\rotatedpagenumber}

\begin{document}
\blindtext[1000]% Lets exaggerate ;-)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The solution was simple. I just need to use the `rotating` package. Thanks @cfr.

```
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\renewcommand{\thepage}{{\large \raisebox{-3em}{\hspace{7in}\begin{rotate}{-90}\ifnum\value{page}<10 000\else 00\fi\arabic{page}\end{rotate}}}}
```

Comment: This is will bite you in the end if you have something like `\tableofcontents` or `\section` in your document